# Getting the id of checkbox from another web form to current web form to configure

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a checkbox in "User Profile" web form page to select the "Gender" search box with ID= "gender".

And on another page called "Admin", I have a checkbox to configure whether I need the gender detail from the user or not.

So, I need to pass the ID name of the checkbox **from the user web form** to **Admin web form** to select "Yes" - for need the detail & "No" for don't want that.

By selecting Yes the checkbox in User web form will be enabled & "No" will disable the checkbox

Comment: I think you got it backwards. What you need is the Database/Session Storage to store the selection of both pages and work with them from any Form. Trying to access the UI to get data is always a faulty idea.

Comment: Also the gender selection is not even a Admin decision. It is a language one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0j74jcxSunY

Comment: I have the session for the "Admin" to configure "Yes" or "No". But I don't have the session for the "Gender" checkbox I just put an id named "gender" only. So, that I got  stuck to retrieve the ID of gender checkbox to Admin .aspx.cs page

Comment: Again: You got a backend storage of some kind. That is where you store teh selection of the checkbox everytime the page is post back. That is where you retreive it from any other page. The Average Dynamic Webpage stops **existing** in memory after it was send to the user. That is the rule of the page lifecycle: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx

Comment: Yes. Finally, I did it. There was a Permission List which takes the ID of the details from the database & I compared them & did it successfully. Thanks for the video & the Life Cycle Article